# Invalid Group with Regex Expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I've looked around for solutions to my problem but I cannot see what part of my regex expression is invalid (javascript says that I have an invalid group). I imagine that I am using something which isn't support by javascript's regex engine?

I'm trying to validate US phone numbers like the following:

```
555-555-5555
(555)555-5555
(555) 555-5555
555 555 5555
5555555555
1 555 555 5555
```

And my expression for validations is:

```
1?[\s-]?\(?(\d{3})\)?[\s-]?(\d{3})[\s-]?(\d{4})
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`/1?[\s-]?\(?(\d{3})\)?[\s-]?(\d{3})[\s-]?(\d{4})/` works fine in JavaScript.

However, my crystal ball says you're using a string that you're passing to the `RegExp` constructor:

```
new RegExp("1?[\s-]?\(?(\d{3})\)?[\s-]?(\d{3})[\s-]?(\d{4})")
```

This is wrong because backslashes have a special meaning in strings, so

```
"1?[\s-]?\(?(\d{3})\)?[\s-]?(\d{3})[\s-]?(\d{4})"
```

is equivalent to

```
"1?[s-]?(?(d{3}))?[s-]?(d{3})[s-]?(d{4})"
```

(because `"\("` is `"("`). That would complain about an invalid group at `(?(`.

Solution: Either use a regex literal (`/.../`) or double your backslashes in the string.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I missed and that explains why the grouping was invalid.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried below ?

```
^\([0-9]{3}\)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$
```

Comment: Answers of the form "Try this:" and a line of code are not really helpful.  An answer should provide a solution, but the real value comes from explaining why the OP's own solution didn't work.